# Keyboard shortcut for buy and sell in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: keyboard, cookie-clicker

When making golden cookie combos with the "Force Hand of Fate" spell you need to quickly sell close to all of your "Wizard Towers" to cast the spell a second time. Then you need to buy a large amount of Wizard Towers before using a sugar lump and do the combo again. So for one execution you need to sell/buy towers 4 times.

To sell I simply hold down Ctrl to buy/sell 10 and Shift to buy/sell 100. The problem is that I need to go with my mouse to the buy/sell toggle to change sell/buy mode. This takes a lot of time and the chances are quite high that you can mess up big time and use all your savings on wizard towers, because you thought that you were in sell mode e.g. missclick.

Is there a hotkey/keyboard shortcut to switch the modes?

[image: Buy/Sell buttons highlighted in red]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is not.  But I have made a bookmarklet that will use the alt key for selling (browser only):
`javascript:document.onkeydown = function(e) {var key = key || e.keyCode;if (key == 18) {Game.storeBulkButton(1);}};document.onkeyup = function(e) {var key = key || e.keyCode;if (key == 18) {Game.storeBulkButton(0);}};`  Just highlight and drag into the browser bookmark bar and you're good.

Unminified version:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = key || e.keyCode;
    if (key == 18) {
        Game.storeBulkButton(1);
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = key || e.keyCode;
    if (key == 18) {
        Game.storeBulkButton(0);
    }
};
```

Comment: Also, the Cookie monster extension can block bulk buying if you can't buy all of them at once.  `javascript:Game.LoadMod("https://cookiemonsterteam.github.io/CookieMonster/dist/CookieMonster.js");`  Also a bookmarklet.

Comment: is cookie monster worth it? i was wondering if i should try it out